# VERBOSE-2: Platform_view_layer.cc(28) - Trying to embed a platform view but the PaintContext does not support embedding

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, inappbrowser, flutter-dependencies

- Trying to open in_app_bowser in flutter iOS app, but unable to open it, it just loading and the show plain white screen.

Answer (score 10):

> Updated :

***The same problem was resolved for me after I adding below simple lines of code in info.plist file ;***

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

below image is helpful for you;

[image]